# SQL DB2 - Select query based on a column value unique to another column

Tags: sql, db2, distinct, unique-constraint

I have a table with following fields:

```
ID    |   Attribute_ID
200          3
200          4
200          6
200          7
201          6
202          2
202          6
203          6
204          2
204          4
204          6
```

I want my result to be like this:

```
ID    |   Attribute_ID
201          6
203          6
```

Basically, I need to write a query that has 'ID' associated with 'Attribute_ID' = 6 and not with 'Attribute_ID' = 1,2,3. That is a column value unique to another column value, if that makes any sense.

I am using DB2.

Below is my attempt, but I am sure I am doing it wrong way.

```
SELECT qa.ID, qa.ATTRIBUTE_ID
    FROM QUESTION_ATTRIBUTES qa
    WHERE(
            (qa.ID,qa.ATTRIBUTE_ID) IN (Values (qa.ID,4),(qa.ID,6),(qa.ID,7))
        AND (qa.ID,qa.ATTRIBUTE_ID) NOT IN (Values (qa.ID,1),(qa.ID,2),(qa.ID,3))            
        )
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select qa.id
from question_attributes
group by qa.id
having min(Attribute_ID) = 6 and max(Attribute_ID) = 6;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think it will work. by changing the last sentence 'having min(Attribute_ID) = 4 and max(Attribute_ID) = 7;'

Comment: @Kartik . . . That change would not answer your question, which is about attribute "6".  If you actually need another condition, you can probably do it with the `having` clause.